# Filtering an Array of Objects with a String + Array of Strings

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I am attempting to understand how to better use functional programming to achieve cleanliness of code. Ideally, I'd like to use `ramda.js` for this, but I'm open to any other functional library.

I have two parameters:

1. `emailSearchTerm` String
2. `[{ value: 'ACTIVE'}, { value: 'INACTIVE'}]` Array of Objects

I have an array I desire to filter by the two parameters above:

```
[
  {
    email: '123@example.com',
    status: 'ACTIVE'
  },
  {
    email: '1234@stackoverflow.com',
    status: 'INACTIVE'
  },
]
```

How would one use a pure function that leverages two inputs to effectively filter through an array of objects?

EDIT: Great followup questions:

For now I have used partial filtering using the search term:

```
searchTerm ? userList.filter(user => user.email.toLowerCase()
    .indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1) : userList
```

userList represents the array of objects, while my searchTerm ternary function looks for partial matches. My goal is to extend this function to additionally take an array of status' -- and I'd like to do so in a clean, functional style that is easy to read -- something outside my current skill level. To summarize, the criteria is:

1. Partial match via email input to email property in userList
2. Full match in status
3. both parameters need to be satisfied

Comment: What is the value of `emailSearchTerm`? What is the desired result? Which all fields need to be looked up? What is the criteria that governs whether there is a match or not?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @ilrein I have updated my answer to your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `.filter` and check if `email` property contains `emailSearchTerm` string with `.includes()` function, and use `.some`(which will test whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. ) for checking and filtering via `status` property

```js
const emailSearchTerm = '123@example.com';
const arrayCheck = [{ value: 'ACTIVE'}, { value: 'INACTIVE'}];

const userList = [
  {
    email: '123@example.com',
    status: 'ACTIVE'
  },
  {
    email: '1234@stackoverflow.com',
    status: 'INACTIVE'
  },
]

const pureFunction = (string, arrayCheck, data) =>
   data.filter(item =>
      item.email.includes(string)
      && arrayCheck.some(obj => obj.value === item.status));

console.log(pureFunction(emailSearchTerm, arrayCheck, userList));
```

**EDIT**

my code was updated, I added filter functional into pure function, so you can use it as a pure function with the same data types as now

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible approach using vanilla JavaScript.

I take advantage of currying and partial application. Check how what matches email can be any *matcher*. I provide the `partialMatch` but you could implement any functions to give more complex matchers.

```js
const equals = x => y => x === y

const contains = xs => x => 
     xs.some (equals (x))
     
const partialMatch = x => y => y.toLowerCase().indexOf (x.toLowerCase()) > -1

// Note that turning that array of objects with  { value: '[STATUS]' }
// should be transformed to an array of string to make things simpler!
const anyStatus = contains (['ACTIVE', 'INACTIVE'])
const activeStatus = contains (['ACTIVE'])

const matchUser = containsStatus => emailMatcher => userList =>
      userList.filter (({ email, status }) =>
          emailMatcher (email)
          && containsStatus (status)
      )

const matchAnyUserStatus = matchUser (anyStatus)
const matchActiveUser = matchUser (activeStatus)

const emailHasAt = partialMatch ('@')
const emailHas123 = partialMatch ('123')

const userList = [{
    email: '123@example.com',
    status: 'ACTIVE'
  },
  {
    email: '1234@stackoverflow.com',
    status: 'INACTIVE'
  }
]

const output1 = matchAnyUserStatus (emailHasAt) (userList)
const output2 = matchAnyUserStatus (emailHas123) (userList)
const output3 = matchActiveUser (emailHas123) (userList)

console.log (output1)
console.log (output2)
console.log (output3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com):

```js
const {curry, contains, __, where, filter} = R; // Ramda

const search = curry(function (statuses, emailMatch, list) {
  const email = contains(emailMatch);
  const status = contains(__, statuses);
  return filter(where({email, status}), list);
});

const userList = [
  {email: 'john@stackoverflow.com', status: 'ACTIVE'},
  {email: 'david@gmail.com', status: 'ACTIVE'},
  {email: 'peter@gmail', status: 'INACTIVE'},
  {email: 'tom@stackoverflow.com', status: 'INACTIVE'}
];

const searchActiveUsers = search(['ACTIVE']);
const searchAllUsers = search(['ACTIVE', 'INACTIVE']);
const searchActiveSoUsers = searchActiveUsers('stackoverflow');
const searchAllGmailUsers = searchAllUsers('gmail');

console.log(searchActiveSoUsers(userList)); // john
console.log(searchAllGmailUsers(userList)); // david & peter
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

---

Quick explanation:

**curry**

Takes a function and returns a function that keeps returning a function until all parameters have been supplied. Example:

```
const sum = curry((a, b, c) => a + b + c);
sum(10)(20)(30); //=> 60
sum(10, 20)(30); //=> 60
sum(10, 20, 30); //=> 60
```

This allows you to create functions bound with specific parameters:

```
const searchActiveUsers = search(['ACTIVE']);
const searchActiveSoUsers = searchActiveUsers('stackoverflow');
searchActiveSoUsers(userList); // john
```

**contains**

Takes a value and a list and returns true if value is found in the list: (In Ramda, strings and arrays are lists.)

```
contains('stackoverflow.com', 'john@stackoverflow.com'); //=> true
contains('ACTIVE', ['ACTIVE', 'INACTIVE']); //=> true
```

**__**

This is a "placeholder" parameter for curried functions. It allows us to specify parameters later on:

```
const foundInJohn = contains(__, 'john@stackoverflow.com');
foundInJohn('stackoverflow'); //=> true
foundInJohn('gmail'); //=> false
```

**where**

Takes an object of functions and another object and returns true if the second object properties return true when applied to their corresponding functions in the first object:

```
const soUser = where({email: contains('stackoverflow')});
soUser({email: 'john@stackoverflow.com'}); //=> true
soUser({email: 'david@gmail.com'}); //=> false
```

**filter**

This is sort of similar to the native filter method on the Array prototype.

```
const filterGmail = filter(contains('gmail'));
filterGmail(['david@gmail.com', 'john@stackoverflow.com']); //=> ['david@gmail.com']
```